# Mule Deployment Error

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I am trying to deploy my mule project to a mule standalone server.
This exception is being raised, anyone can help me please.

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:139)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:269)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(ArchiveDeployer.java:290)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(ArchiveDeployer.java:257)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.ArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(ArchiveDeployer.java:110)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:144)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:94)
        at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52)
        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/387927

TL;DR you're running Mule with a JVM that's older than 1.7. Time to upgrade!